# script to delete millions of rows from a oracle table based on either age or date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

Is there a possiblity to write a script in oracle which deletes the rows from a table based on the age. i.e., I want to delete the rows s. I have a table with millions of rows in it and I want to keep only the latest 3 months rows. I have the following table with column names as

I am very new to database stuff. How can I write a script for this?

Comment: Try it yourself, but do it as a 'select' query to test your where clause. once you're sure the data looks correct, do a backup, then switch to an actual 'delete' query.

Comment: ORA_ROWSCN, I'm not sure if its supported in Oracle9i

Comment: @Raghavendar - What is the data type of `FEED_DT_TM`?  If it is a `DATE`, you don't want to call `TO_DATE` on it.  If it is a `VARCHAR2`, you almost certainly want to use a format mask that matches the format of the string.  From a data model standpoint, it ought to be a `DATE`.

Comment: data type of FEED_DT_TM is Date.

Comment: @Justin - Is it better to write  a single query to perform the above operation or a script. Since I want to keep only the first 2 months of data in the table.

Comment: @Marc B: I first tried with select statement instead delete. It worked for me. But, DO i need to include this one into a script and whta all I need to consider while writing a script. Please advise

Answer (score 2):

With this many rows deleted in a single transaction you should also predict that much undo space will be used. All the rows that you delete will be briefly saved in the undo tablespace to allow you to rollback transaction and, more importantly, to allow other users to see the rows until you COMMIT your delete. See [this asktom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:2345591157689) for advice.

Answer (score 1):

Since `FEED_DT_TM` is a `DATE`, there is no need to use `TO_DATE` to cast it to a `DATE`.  Simply

```
DELETE FROM your_table_name
 WHERE sysdate - feed_dt_tm >= 120
```

Comment: Thank you very much . I am still confused whether to go for a single delete statement to delete around 12 million rows from my table. Is there any way to perform the same operation differently like writing a script and running it . I am concerned that it takes longer time to perform the above delete operation.

Comment: @Raghavendar - There are other ways to delete large numbers of rows.  Those ways will, however, take longer, consume more resources, and be harder to write and test.  A single `DELETE` statement is the most efficient way to delete large numbers of rows.

Comment: Thank You Sir. I have my concerns cleared now. I will perform the above operation after discussing it with my DBA. Actually, my DBA asked me to write a script instead of delete statement I will let him know

Answer (score 1):

Also consider the option of keeping the rows you need in a new table and then dropping the old table.

Something like..

```
create table new_table_2_months
as
select * 
  from table1
  where date_column > (sysdate-60)

drop table table1;

alter table new_table_2_months rename to table1;
```

**Make sure you also look at constraints, indexes and other objects, if applicable to the initial table. And don't forget to TEST, TEST, TEST.**